# How to configure installer in tauri

Tags: tauri

I am new to tauri development,is there any way to configure nsis(installer) change application icon ,final banner image, and enable/disable run application after installing the app  just like electron package.json build configuration

Comment: This is more an nsis question than a Tauri one. Except if Tauri manages the full configuration of the installer (shame, that is uses nsis, when InnoSetup is so mature).

Comment: There's no way to do it afaik currently that doesn't involve a very custom solution for it. The reason you're not supposed to tweak the installer more than what existing options allow you to is because Tauri is intended to make bundles available on several platforms, so giving users too much control over the bundling process is, while not impossible, not a priority